# Data binding error with feature module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding

The xml layout file and the view holder are all correct, so I still don't know why I am getting this error.

My colleagues have all double checked it already. I have created a module which holds the app module and now this error comes up.

I would appreciate any ideas or help!

**Error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':apk_holder:compileBetaDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.laurence.ui.TitleMvvm.ViewModel.onClick and java.lang.Object has 0 abstract methods, so is not resolved as a listener
  file:D:\laur\Documents\Apps\TestApp\app\src\main\res\layout\title.xml
  loc:17:23 - 17:33
  ****\ data binding error ****
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.laurence.ui.NotesMvvm.ViewModel.onClick and java.lang.Object has 0 abstract methods, so is not resolved as a listener
file:D:\laur\Documents\Apps\TestApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_notes.xml
      loc:21:23 - 21:33
      loc:61:27 - 61:37
      ****\ data binding error ****
      ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.laurence.ui.SplashMvvm.ViewModel.onClick and java.lang.Object has 0 abstract methods, so is not resolved as a listener
      file:D:\laur\Documents\Apps\TestApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_splash.xml
      loc:26:31 - 26:52
      ****\ data binding error ****
      ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.laurence.ui.NewMvvm.ViewModel.onClick and java.lang.Object has 0 abstract methods, so is not resolved as a listener
  file:D:\laur\Documents\Apps\TestApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_new.xml
      loc:31:35 - 31:52
      ****\ data binding error ****
```

**title.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.laurence.ui.TitleMvvm.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:onClick="@{vm::onClick}">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**TitleScreen.kt**

```
interface TitleMvvm {
    interface View : MvvmView

    interface ViewModel : MvvmViewModel<View>{
        @get:Bindable
        val isClickableSection: Boolean

        fun onClick()
    }
}

class TitleDelegate : BaseActivity<TitleViewHolder> {

    override fun createViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): TitleViewHolder = Utils.createViewHolder(parent, R.layout.title, ::TitleViewHolder)

    override fun bindViewHolder(viewHolder: TitleViewHolder, list: List<SectionItem>, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.viewModel.update(list[position])
    }
}

class TitleViewHolder constructor(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<TitleBinding, TitleMvvm.ViewModel>(itemView), TitleMvvm.View {

    init {
        viewHolderComponent.inject(this)
        bindContentView(itemView)
    }
}

@PerViewHolder
open class TitleViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private var navigator: Navigator,
            private var urlHandler: UrlHandler) : BaseViewModel<TitleMvvm.View>(), TitleMvvm.ViewModel {

    override fun onClick() {
        if (isClickableSection) {
           // yet to do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added `android:onClick="someMethod()"` in xml?

Comment: can you please provide activity class code and xml

Comment: @ND1010_ added the code

Comment: ok checking please try with my answer

Comment: I'll do it in 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem.

So solution is Change to **Project View** -> **Remove/Delete** `.Gradle` and `.idea` folder -> Rebuild project -> Done

Replace  `app:onClick="@{vm::onClick}"` with  `android:onClick="@{vm::onClick}"`

Comment: hello @Laurence you have to replace prefix  with android instead of app

Comment: And also i think he should pass in the `View` parameter to onClick () method since he is referring method from xml.